# How do I find the asymptotic tight bound to this recurrence? T(n) = T(n-2) + n log (n/2)

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence

The T(n-2) part confuses me a bit because if I find T(n-2) and substitute it into T(n) = T(n-2) + n log(n/2), for this part, does k = 2 or 3?

Also, what happens with T(n-1)?

Do I just not acknowledge it or how am I supposed to apply it to solve this recurrence?

How would I approach this recurrence and solve it? (I approached it using the substitution method, but am not sure how to solve it)

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + nlog(n/2)
```

Comment: Can you solve `F(n) = F(n-1) + n/2 log(n/4)`? Then `T(n) = F(n/2)`.

Comment: @YakovGalka I don't understand why I would need to do that?

Comment: Seems like the recurrence has an upper bound of `O(n^2 * ln (n/2))`.

Comment: @AKSingh can you explain how you were able to get that?

Comment: I am not sure if i am correct or not.

Comment: The base case for recurrence is n=2 ?

Comment: @ManavChhibber it doesn't say, the only thing it says is "Assume T(n) is a constant for sufficiently small n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the recurrence relation consists of two indepenedent parts, the even entries and the odd entries. You need two initial values, one for T_0 and one for T_1.

Consider `n` even, then `T(n) = T(2k)` for `k=n/2`.
Let `F(k) = T(2k)`. our equation becomes

```
F(k) = F(k-1) + 2 k log(k)
     = 2 k log(k) + 2 (k-1) log(k-1) + .. 2 1 log(1) + T_0
     = 2 sum i log(i) + T_0
```

Now we know that within the sum `log(i) < log(k)`, so we get

```
F(k) < 2 log(k) sum i + T_0
     = 2 log(k) k * (k+1) / 2 + T0
     = log(k) k * (k+1) + T_0
     = O(k^2 log(k))
```

so, for even n:

```
T(n) = O(n^2 log(n))
```

Proving the same holds for odd `n` is similar.